# How much actual performance is lost with extreme negative camber / "stanced" vehicles?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, friction

I recently had a discussion with a friend, who's intuition is that "stanced" cars with extreme negative camber angles are losing a huge fraction of their performance, such that a 5.0L V8 Mustang "stanced" would lose to a cheap naturally aspirated Honda Civic, or something like 50% of its performance, wholly due to the loss in traction.

[image: Stanced Mustang]

His quote: "This car, slammed like this is slower than an eco box."

And also: "i would be supprised if it could even launch at all without just uncontrolled tire spin."

However intuitive this may seem to him, the coefficient of friction is entirely independent of the contact patch area. There are other negative aspects to a tire like this, in that it will wear down much faster with the same compound / same tire, and the sidewalls will need to support more of the load (or, at least, one of the sidewalls). Independent of whether this is a 'good idea' or not, is there any actual data about 1/4 mile times at reasonable vs extreme camber angles with the same car and the same tires?

My intuition is that the graph will of course peak at 0° for drag/straight line racing, and -1° to -4° for tracks depending on the banking level - higher for NASCAR, lower for flat corners, but that this is a relatively small bump and that not a whole lot of performace is lost at the more extreme angles, say 10-20%.

Here's an article divorcing the idea that more contact patch necessarily equates to more friction: [Laws of Friction, with Applications to Motorcycling](https://www.stevemunden.com/friction.html)

> ## The Second Law of Friction
>
> Although the friction force depends on the normal force, the second law of friction says that friction force does NOT depend on the area of contact between the object and the surface. Imagine if you turned a box so that less of it was touching the floor. Would that change the normal force? No! The box still weighs the same, so the normal force doesn't change, even if the area of contact does.
> [The Five Laws of Friction](https://study.com/academy/lesson/the-five-laws-of-friction.html)

However, what I'm really looking for is real data, not theoretical formulas.

To visualize the disagreement, it's really about the extreme tail end of the graph here, not the relatively normal range from +5° to -5°.

[image: Camber Angle vs Performance]

Comment: Those "laws of friction" are only "true" for high-school physics problems and experiments. They work fairly well for sliding blocks of wood down inclined planes in a lab experiment, but they don't apply to most real-world situations, and certainly not to high performance car tires. See https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/1526796 for a few examples of more modern friction models - and there are many more than the ones in that paper.

Comment: @alephzero This article disputes your comment, https://www.stevemunden.com/friction.html. I'll read yours and compare the differences.

Comment: The research paper from the US DOE (offered by @alephzero) has conducted model analysis and mentioned the term "nonlinear damping phenomena" in the conclusion that may provide some insight on how the friction force is affected by the contact area. https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/1526796

Comment: I'll be more concerned with "stability" while making sharp turns as "side friction" and "inertia force" will get into the picture.

Comment: @r13 The stevemunden.com article seems to be all over the place, but since it's first reference is a first-year physics textbook, it seems to be just re-hashing Coulomb's theory of friction proposed more than 200 years ago. Sadly, high school kids seem to be taught that "Coulomb's laws of friction" have the same universal validity as "Newton's laws of motion. They don't.

Comment: @alephzero More support for the HS stuff: "**Laws of dry friction**
The elementary property of sliding (kinetic) friction were discovered by experiment in the 15th to 18th centuries and were expressed as three empirical laws:
Amontons' First Law: The force of friction is directly proportional to the applied load.
**Amontons' Second Law:** The force of friction is independent of the apparent area of contact.""
Coulomb's Law of Friction: Kinetic friction is independent of the sliding velocity. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction

Comment: @alephzero "There are five laws of friction and they are:

The friction of the moving object is proportional and perpendicular to the normal force.
The friction experienced by the object is dependent on the nature of the surface it is in contact with.
**Friction is independent of the area of contact as long as there is an area of contact.**
Kinetic friction is independent of velocity.
The coefficient of static friction is greater than the coefficient of kinetic friction.
https://byjus.com/physics/friction-laws-of-friction/ I hope they are not all wrong.

Comment: @r13, clearly the contact patch of vehicle tires matter; race cars don't use skinny tires. You can look up studies all you want, the reality on the ground is that contact patch matters.  The proof is in the world around us, unless you think that auto designers and race teams are all wrong on the issue.

Comment: @TigerGuy One of the referred articles indicates the main reason for the use of wider tires is due to wear and tear. If you disagree with all those writings, please provide your source to dispute the notion they made, not me, as I was a doubter before.

Comment: @r13, the first is halfway true (friction is perpendicular to the normal force, but the relationship between the normal force and the friction force is more complicated than a simple proportionality relation), the second is universally true, and the last three are false, but close enough to true for most purposes.  The true nature of friction is complicated enough that they offer PhDs in it.  The page you linked is an example of a [lie-to-undergrads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children).

Comment: @Mark I challenge you to write your own answer to uncover the myth/lies you've claimed with the linked reference. I couldn't find any article that says "we don't fully understand friction after thousands of years, it is a phenomenon that remains to be solved :) If there is one, I'll be delighted to read it.

Comment: @r13, why should I do so, [when someone else has already done a good job?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/154485/40686)

Comment: @Mark The linked answer upheld the second law but argued the 1st and 3rd. IMO, the first law is still 100% true if the rigid body assumption was made for both elements (in mechanics, N is represented by an arrow without worrying denting). For the third, it is refined work incorporates "viscosity" in the mix, which I have no background information, so no comment.

Comment: @Mark I saw an article that says the car gains more "traction" with wider tires, and found the definitions interesting: **Friction** - The rubbing of one object or surface against another. **Traction** - the act of pulling something along a surface using motive power. It is something worth to think about.